# How do I implement Rating Bar in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, ratingbar

I am using PCL xamarin form having two project android and IOS.

I want to implement Rating bar in xamarin.forms.

I search for the same but did not help me.

Please suggest me How to implement Rating Bar

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/55915640/8488390

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at these two articles:

- https://blog.xamarin.com/behaviors-in-xamarin-forms/
- http://blog.falafel.com/xamarin-rate-this-article/

The main feature to look at are [behaviors](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/behaviors/).